# Embed Object in the existing Excel Worksheet using ClosedXML

Tags: vb.net, winforms, closedxml

I want to insert OLE object- 'A worksheet' into an existing Worksheet through code. It's possible using interop, the same can be achieved through closedXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the same can be achieved through closedXML?

No, ClosedXML doesn't support embedded objects.